# Java interface not enforced

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class definition:

```
public class SyrianEdge extends BaseEdge<SyrianVertex, SyrianEdge> 
                        implements Weighted, Blockable{
    ...
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface Weighted{
    public long getWeight();
}
```

The class SyrianEdge **doesn't** have the method `public long getWeight()` but everything seems to compile fine.

What am I missing? How come the interface doesn't force the class to have its methods?

Comment: Does `BaseEdge` implement this method ?

Comment: lol, thanks. too many classes to manage :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at this basic example :

```
interface Weighted{
    public long getWeight();
}

abstract class Parent implements Weighted {

    @Override
    public long getWeight() {
        return 0;
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {}
```

Since the `Parent` class already implements this method, there is no obligations for the `Child` class to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

since you are extending `BaseEdge`, one can safely assume that `BaseEdge` implements Weighted and implemented the method `getWeight()`.

if any one of the class in the inheritance tree implements an interface `I` then using the `implement I` on any class **down** the tree would produce no errors as it has been already implemented (except the case in which all the classes up the tree are abstract s the first concrete class should implement all the methods declared in the Interface I).